# Use views as radios (or check-box) options in drupal forms

Tags: 7, views, forms

Here is the scenario:

There is a multistep form for creating a content type "**Support request**".

**Step 1:** In this step, the user enters his/her device model and click next.

**Step 2:** In the next step, a list of technician (technician is a content type) whom has knowledge about that certain device will be shown, in this steps some information about technician is shown (from node) and user can decide which technician to hire.

**Step 3:** In the last step, some information about device problem is submitted by user and the form is submitted.

Now the question :

> Is there any solution to use views in second step? How can a view like this (note that the view output should be filtered based on the device model selected in first step) can be passed as radios options in drupal forms?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using one of listed module :

[Views attach](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_attach)

> This module provides two additional Views display plugins, "Profile"
>   and "Node content". These displays do not display on a page but get
>   "attached" to either a user page or nodes of specified types.

[Entity Views Attachment](https://www.drupal.org/project/eva)

> "Eva" is short for "Entity Views Attachment;" it provides a Views
>   display plugin that allows the output of a View to be attached to the
>   content of any Drupal entity. The body of a node or comment, the
>   profile of a user account, or the listing page for a Taxonomy term are
>   all examples of entity content.

[View field](https://www.drupal.org/project/viewfield)

> View field provides a field that holds a reference to a View and
>   renders it whenever the entity containing the field is displayed.